# how to use SSH in different platforms?

Tags: c++

I am using QT libraries in my C++ applications, I would like to know if there is a multiplatform library to use SSH without portability problems.

I need a ssh client to connect to my server and send files.

Comment: Maybe you can bundle your application with the SSH client, like Git on Windows does and rely on the existing scp client in Linux/Mac OS?

Comment: I think you're confusing two concepts.  A SSH *library* will help embed SSH functionality into your application.  A SSH *client* is a standalone program that you can use to establish a connection to and SSH server.  Do you need to embed the client inside your application, or are you using the SSH client separately?

Answer (score 1):

[OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.org/) is a FOSS implementation of the SSH protocol with built-in client and server programs.  Though the OpenSSH project doesn't seem to officially support Windows (and even [recommends alternatives](http://www.openssh.org/windows.html)), Windows ports exist. [SSHWindows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/) seems like a promising effort, although I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I use cryptlib:
http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/cryptlib/

Is is very easy to use and has a free and commercial license.